# como puedo consultar tres tablas de las cuales a y b comparten un id y b y c comparten otro id?

Tags: mysql

Con esta insercion trae  los  datos principales y  un slo familiar,donde debo poner el CONCAT y que debo descartar?.

```
"SELECT * FROM paciente

LEFT JOIN historia_clinica_tsocial ON historia_clinica_tsocial.paci_doc = paciente.paci_doc

LEFT JOIN familia_tsocial ON familia_tsocial.hct_id = historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_id

WHERE paciente.paci_doc='$hct_id'



GROUP BY paciente.paci_doc





 ";
```

esta consulta esta bien pero  solo muestra un  familiar asociado y son varios.Lo muestro asi por que en mysql es muy extenso pero es exactamente lo mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Esta consulta hace lo que necesito,pero la duplica.

```
$sql= "SELECT 

historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_id,
historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_fecha,
historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_a,
historia_clinica_tsocial.paci_doc,
historia_clinica_tsocial.empl_doc,

paciente.paci_doc,
paciente.paci_nom,
paciente.paci_ape,

familia_tsocial.fts_id,
familia_tsocial.fts_nombre,
 familia_tsocial.fts_apellido,
 familia_tsocial.fts_parentezco,
 familia_tsocial.fts_edad,
 familia_tsocial.fts_escolaridad,
 familia_tsocial.fts_ocupacion,
 familia_tsocial.fts_vive,
 familia_tsocial.hct_id



FROM paciente, historia_clinica_tsocial,familia_tsocial

WHERE paciente.paci_doc=historia_clinica_tsocial.paci_doc 


AND  historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_id=familia_tsocial.hct_id

AND historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_id='$hct_id'  ";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera saber que tipo de JOIN se  puede utilizar para consultar  varios  datos de tres tablas.La cuestion es asi.

tabla paciente tiene un id  llamado paci_doc.
tabla historia_clinica_tsocial tiene un id  llamado hct_id.
tabla familia_tsocial tiene un id  llamado fts_id.

historia_clinica_tsocial hereda el id de paciente.
familia_tsocial heredad el id  de historis_clinica_tsocial.

quisiera consultar todos los datos de las tres tablas asociadas a un paciente con su respectiva  historia clinica

la primera captura,la que tiene dos filas es la continiacion  de tabla historia_clinica_tsocial,tiene 42,columnas por eso va cortada.

Comment: Sería ideal si puede especificar detalladamente los tres ID de cada tabla y adjuntar una foto o captura de pantalla de las tres tablas para ver que tipo de relación se puede implementar.

Comment: Acabe de añadir las tablas,si notas la tabla paciente tiene una PK paci_doc ,la cual pasa a ser  foranea en historia_clinica_social,esta ultima tabla tiene una PK llamada hct_id que es  serial,esta pk  pasa a ser foranea en familia_tsocial que  a su vez tiene una llave PK llamada fts_id

Answer (score 1):

```
select p, h, f 
from paciente p 
inner join historia_clinica_tsocial h 
inner join familia_tsocial f on p.paci_doc = h.hct_id 
and f.fts_id = h.hct_id;
```

Comment: Se te agradece la ayuda, pero responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, por favor se tan amable de editar y explicar como esto soluciona la pregunta del OP

Comment: De hecho  intente asi pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Según los ID que comentas las relaciones podrían quedar así. Por favor intenta el siguiente código:

```
SELECT * FROM paciente
LEFT JOIN historia_clinica_tsocial ON historia_clinica_tsocial.paci_doc = paciente.paci_doc
LEFT JOIN famila_tsocial ON familia_tsocial.hct_id = historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_id
```

- La relación entre h_c_T y paciente sería: paci.doc
- La relación entre f_tsocial y h_c_ts sería: hct_id

Con el primer LEFT JOIN se trae todos los datos de la tabla h_c_t que tengan el mismo paci.doc, entre ellos hct_id, luego con el segundo LEFT JOIN trae los datos de familia_tsocial que tengan el mismo hct_id, por lo que le va traer todos los registros, puede completar con un **WHERE paci.doc=valoronumero** si quiere limitar a un solo usuario. Debería funcionar, saludos!

**Actualización**

```
SELECT 
historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_id,
historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_fecha,
historia_clinica_tsocial.hct_a,
historia_clinica_tsocial.paci_doc,
historia_clinica_tsocial.empl_doc,
paciente.paci_doc,
paciente.paci_nom,
paciente.paci_ape,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',',familia_tsocial.fts_id,familia_tsocial.fts_nombre,familia_tsocial.fts_apellido,familia_tsocial.fts_parentezco,familia_tsocial.fts_edad,familia_tsocial.fts_escolaridad,familia_tsocial.fts_ocupacion,familia_tsocial.fts_vive,familia_tsocial.hct_id)) as familiar
```

El campo "Familiar" va devolver todos los datos de todos los familiares que existan, en ese mismo orden, uno a uno. En PHP debes usar la función explode para imprimir los datos. Espero sea de ayuda, en caso de responder su duda no olvides marcar la respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: Tu solucion funciona,pero olvide mencionar que cada historia puede tener mas de un familiar asociado,por eso se repite la historia por  cada familiar,o no se si sea un  error mio al mostrarlo en el formulario.

Comment: Claro, si las otras tablas tienen mas registros se van a ir mostrando, puedes agruparlos al final de la consulta con un `GROUP BY paciente.paci_doc`esto solo te mostraría un registro pero no conocerías los otros familiares, de ser posible toma una captura de pantalla del resultado de la consulta con la modificación que hiciste y su código.

Comment: Hizo exactamente eso, trajo la historia asociada al paciente,pero solo muestra un  familiar asociado y  debe mostrarlos todos,cabe destacar que solo muestra una tablas que era una de las  condiciones,no es posible mostrar todos los familiares en una sola tabla?

Comment: ya adjunte un  pantallazo de la impresion,se puede hacer algo mas?

Comment: Se puede hacer  una doble consulta dentro de la misma funcion y mostrar los familiares  en otra tablas por aparte?

Comment: @Yero la pregunta es muy amplia para tan poca información que brindas, desconozco los datos que almacenas de los familiares y que tipo de info quieres mostrar, pero te sugiero buscar acerca de `GROUP_CONCAT()` esto uniría los datos de una columna en especifico, por ejemplo el nombre,apellido,otro dato del familiar y luego con la función explode de PHP lo divides. Actualizo la respuesta...

Comment: Actualice la pregunta,puedes corregir la  consulta?

Comment: Usa el mismo código que puse en la actualización, tal cual como está, me tomé del select que hacías inicialmente para generar esa consulta con el CONCAT, utiliza PHPMYADMIN para correr el SQL y veas el resultado que te da.

Comment: Ese codigo bota error  cerca  del  CONCAT ,lo unico que corregi fuela ultima coma que se encuentra en  el SELECT paciente.paci_ape Y asi tampoco funciona en phpMyadmin.Gracias igual.

Comment: Es cierto, no funciona porque no tiene los JOINS ni el FROM, olvidé incluirlos en la actualización, revisa nuevamente incluyendo esas dos funciones. En ese mismo orden que está el código incluye el FROM y luego los dos JOINS.

Comment: Podrias colocar la insercion completa? No funciona pero no se  este ignorando algo.